# AWS SQSConnection multiple queues

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

I have a use-case where my application needs to subscribe to multiple SQS queues and listen to the events. I'm following the official [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html) to use SQS.

However, the example in the docs only cover the case of subscribing to **one** queue. There the flow is basically the following.

```
// 1) create the connection
val connection = factory.createConnection()

// 2) create the session from the connection
val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

// 3) create the queue object from the session
val queue = session.createQueue("my-q-1")

// 4) create a consumer for that queue
val consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)

// 5) start the connection
connection.start()
```

This is simple enough. However, what if I want to subscribe to **two** queues?

1. Do I need 2 connections?
2. Or do I need 1 connection but 2 sessions?
3. Or do I need 1 connection, 1 session, but 2 consumers on the same session?

Any experience around this would really help. Maybe JMS is not the best choice either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use the simplest JMS pattern then you can use 1 connection, 1 session, and 2 consumers.

However, if you're going to use JMS's [`MessageListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) and you want the best performance you'll want to use 1 connection, 2 sessions, 1 consumer on each session, and 1 `MessageListener` on each consumer. This is because JMS sessions are not thread-safe and each `MessageListener` will be invoked asynchronously so if you want the listeners to be able to receive messages concurrently you'll want a session for each.

Comment: Thanks, so `MessageListener` spawns its own thread each time it's invoked? So there's no reason to spawn a new thread / coroutine inside the `onMessage` block, it's already handled by the JMS?

Comment: And once the message is consumed from the queue by consumer A, does it still remain in the queue so that consumer B can consume it too? How do I achieve that? I assume that once I consume it from consumer A, then consumer A will not receive the same message again?

Comment: The message will be delivered to the `MessageListener` in its own thread asynchronously. I can't for sure it will be a _new_ thread specifically because that will depend on the implementation you're using. I know some implementations use a thread pool for better performance versus spawning a new thread every time. Also, I can't say there's "no reason" to create additional threads inside your `onMessage` method as that depends on your use-case.

Comment: If you're using a JMS _queue_ then all the consumers compete for the same messages so once the message is consumed then no other consumer will receive it. If you want every consumer to get every message then you need to use a JMS _topic_.

Comment: There's a question mark at the end of your most recent comment, but I'm not sure if you're really asking a question or just making a statement. In any case, we seem to be diverting from your original question, and you should probably create a new question for this.